# Permission Denied: GitHub workflow access to private npm package in GitHub registry

Tags: github-actions

Following this documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/configuring-a-packages-access-control-and-visibility#github-actions-access-for-organization-owned-container-images

I have one repository publish a private npm package. I have modified repository package settings to grant read access to an other repository github actions.

However, I get permission denied on npm install within GitHub workflow on the repository trying to access this private package.

note: this works fine if I use a PAT token.

What am I missing?

Kind regards

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved without using a PAT. I remember reading about this behavior [here](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/214) with some workarounds if you want to try them.